# Using a class created in a cpp file as an argument type in a header file

Tags: c++

I am going through some code which is a little un-organized.
I would like to use a class created in a cpp file used as an argument type in its header file. I know the class needs to be defined in the header but I am currently looking for a short approach here for now. This is what I have

```
filename: foo.cpp

class bar {
}
```

Now the header

```
filename: foo.h

class teacher {
public:
   void dosomething(bar b) {  ///<-----Incomplete type.
     b.work();   ///
   }
}
```

I tried declaring a prototype inside the header this way

```
class foo;
 class teacher {
    public:
       void dosomething(bar b) {  
         b.work();   ///Error no method work for incomplete type.
       }
    }
```

What would be the simplest way to fix this issue apart from moving the `bar` class to the header file

Comment: "What would be the simplest way to fix this issue" -   Add an include that brings in the definition of "bar".

Comment: I am not sure what that means ?  How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be better like this :

## File : bar.hh

```
class bar 
{
...
}
```

## File : foo.hh

```
#include "bar.hh"
class teacher 
{
public:
   void dosomething(bar b) 
{
     b.work();  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can forward-declare the type `bar` in the header assuming you do nothing that relies on it being a complete type.  For example, this won't work:

```
// foo.hpp
class bar;
class teacher {
public:
   void dosomething(bar b) {
     // Will fail, bar is not complete:
     b.work();
   }
};
```

But this will:

```
// foo.hpp
class bar;
class teacher {
public:
   void dosomething(bar b);
};

// foo.cpp
class bar {
public:
    void work() {}
};

void teacher::dosomething(bar b) {
    b.work();
}
```

However, I would advise instead to create a `bar.hpp` file with the definition of the `bar` type and `#include` it into `foo.hpp`.

Consider, for example, that any code (other than `foo.cpp`) that includes `foo.hpp` will be unable to invoke `teacher::dosomething(bar)`, since it won't have any definition for `bar`.

Comment: Yeah i moved the implimentation to a cpp file and just forward declared the type